# How to display slope on a plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I used the regress function to find the slope for some data I plotted. I have managed to plot the data and the fitted line both on the same plot. I know how to make it clear that the fitted line is the slope, but I would also like to add a box in corner of the graph (dont care where) that shows the actual value of the slope (basically shows the value that the regress function returns), and I'm trying to find a way to do this automatically (like if there's a function for that or something). Can anybody help (I hope I explained my question well enough...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't try to recreate your slope line but have you considered using an annotation?

Example:

```
x = [-1:.2:1];
plot(x,x.^2,'-bo');
annotation('textbox', [.4 .4 .1 .1], 'String', ...
                    ['slope at x = 0.6 is: ',num2str(2*.6)]);
```

Which shows:

[image]

Of course you can control how the box is positioned, formatted, and so forth.

Check the help files for more detailed info.  In some cases you might also consider using a legend().

Comment: Thank you! I like this solution the best, works great and easy!

Answer (score 2):

The function `text` adds text to a figure.  It requires a position and a string to display.  In addition, you can highly customize the appearance of the text.  For example:

```
x = 1:100;
y = randn(size(x)) + 0.3*x;
plot(x,y,'.');

p = polyfit(x,y,1);
hold on;
plot(x, polyval(p,x),'k-');

h = text(min(xlim(gca)), max(ylim(gca)), ...
    sprintf('%fx + %f', p(1), p(2)),...
    'verticalalignment','top',...
    'horizontalalignment','left');
```

Then, to see the various settinsg you can change, look at:

```
get(h)
```

Those properties can almost all be changes at creation (like `verticalalignment` above) or after creation (e.g. set(h,  `verticalalignment`, 'top')).